# Show that $R \otimes_R M\cong M$ is isomorphic to $M$, for every left $R$-module $M$, $R$ a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

My professor says it is trivial, but I cannot still see the triviality :(

> Let $R$ be a ring. Show that $R \otimes_R M\cong M$ for a left $R$-module $M$.

Any ideas how to address this?

Comment: What is R_R? what does underscore represents?

Comment: Sorry, The multiplication R×R→R defines a right R module structure on M=R, denoted for R then we write at the right  of this another R

Comment: Show the canonical map $r\otimes m \mapsto r\cdot m$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you!!! I will do it...

Comment: @MarianoVelásquez Hi: I made some typesetting edits to make your post clearer. You can view what I did by clicking the edit timestamp. Feel free to revert if I did something you did not intend. I think, however, that this is the best way to write what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Since $R$ is an $R-R$ bimodule $R\otimes_R M$ is a left $R$ module. The assignment $(r,m) \rightarrow rm $ defines a middle linear map  $R\times M\rightarrow M$. So there is a group homomorphism $\alpha: R\otimes_R M \rightarrow M$ such that$\alpha(r\otimes m)=rm$. Verify that $\alpha$ is in fact a homomorphism of left R-modules.
Then verify that the map $\beta: M\rightarrow R\otimes_R M$ given by $m \rightarrow 1_{R} \otimes m$ is an $R$-module homomorphism such that $\alpha\beta=1_{M}$ and $\beta\alpha=1_{R\otimes_R M}$.Hence $\alpha:R\otimes_R M \cong M$. The isomorphism $A\otimes_R R \cong A$ is constructed similarly. (This proof is from Hungerford, Graduated Texts in Mathematics, 212 pp.)

Comment: Can't we use the universal property of tensor to show that $M$ is tensor of $A$ and $M$ ? Just by showing that every bilinear map from $ A \times M$ to $X$ factors uniquely through $M$.